# Need to retrieve columns from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are three tables: `dept`, `emp`, `sal` . You can find their structure and data in the images. 
I need to extract the list of employees who have location as pune and have max salary in their department. Since there are five departments, the final output will contain five rows and columns of `emp_id`, `dept`, `dept_id`, `salary`.

[image: Description of tables]
[image: Expected output]

I've tried...

```
  select e.emp_id, dept,e.dept_id, max(sal) as 'highest salary'
    from sal s,emp e,dept d
   where e.emp_id = s.emp_id and d.dept_id = e.dept_id and loc ='Pune'
group by e.emp_id,e.dept_id,dept
order by e.dept_id
```

Comment: Please show some effort in solving this. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please post the code you have tried and you will easily find help.

Comment: select e.emp_id, dept,e.dept_id, max(sal) as 'highest salary' from sal s,emp e,dept d
 where e.emp_id = s.emp_id and d.dept_id = e.dept_id and loc ='Pune'
 group by e.emp_id,e.dept_id,dept
 order by e.dept_id

Comment: i  used this code to try to get the expected output, but it shows duplicate rows of departments , as in it shows all the employees who have location as pune but not the highest salary on each department

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  `MySQL`, `Oracle`, etc?

Comment: It makes it much easier to find a solution if you post data in text format rather than images. Can you cut and paste from whatever app you snipped the images from?

Comment: I am trying to get the output in SQL Management studio @matbailie

Comment: https://fts.capgemini.com/pubpwd/47998131223044/SQL_query_max_sal.xlsx 

username: sqnvegghe

Password: P7AymTDbCk
Use this link and the credentials to download the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t.emp_id, d.dept, d.dept_id, t.sal
from dept d
cross apply ( select top 1 e.emp_id, s.sal as sal
              from emp e 
              inner join sal s on s.emp_id = e.emp_id
              where d.dept_id = e.dept_id and e.loc = 'Pune'
              order by s.sal desc
            ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have window functions *(that depends on whether you're using `MySQL`, `Oracle`, `SQLite`, etc)* you will need to do it in two steps.

Find the highest salary per department *(for employees in 'Pune')*, then another set of joins to find out who those people are.

```
SELECT
  dep.dept,
  dep.dept_id,
  emp.emp_id,
  sal.sal
FROM
  emp
INNER JOIN
  sal
    ON sal.emp_id = emp.emp_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    emp.dept_id,
    MAX(sal.sal)  AS max_sal
  FROM
    emp
  INNER JOIN
    sal
      ON sal.emp_id = emp.emp_id
  WHERE
    emp.loc = 'Pune'
)
  dep_sal
    ON  dep_sal.dept_id = emp.dept_id
    AND dep_sal.max_sal = sal.sal
INNER JOIN
  dep
    ON dep.dept_id = emp.dept_id
WHERE
  emp.loc = 'Pune'
ORDER BY
  dep.dept,
  emp.emp_id
```

***EDIT:***  With SQL Server 2008 on-wards it's a bit easier...

```
WITH
  emp_sal_ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    emp.dept_id,
    emp.emp_id,
    sal.sal,
    RANK(sal.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY emp.dept_id
                            ORDER BY sal.sal
                       )
                         AS rank_sal
  FROM
    emp
  INNER JOIN
    sal
      ON sal.emp_id = emp.emp_id
  WHERE
    emp.loc = 'Pune'
)
SELECT
  dep.dept,
  dep.dept_id,
  emp_sal_ranked.emp_id,
  emp_sal_ranked.sal
FROM
  emp_sal_ranked
INNER JOIN
  dept
    ON dept.dept_id = emp_sal_ranked.dept_id
WHERE
  emp_sal_ranked.rank_sal = 1
ORDER BY
  dep.dept,
  emp_sal_ranked.emp_id
```

Comment: be advised, I am using SQl management studio, here some of the funtcions do not work as they do in oracle and mysql

Comment: both the queries work just fine, thank you so much @MatBailie

Comment: @MovinFernandes : you're welcome.  Feel free to up vote any answers that help you, and accept the answer that helps most.